# Recibo mensaje de File Not Found, cuando el archivo si existe y esta referencciado correctamente y funcional, dejo de funcionar de un día al otro,

Tags: php, mysql, cors, error404, headers

Una aplicación en PHP que funcionaba correctamente, de pronto inicio a enviar mensajes que no se encuentran los archivos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque el archivo si se encuentra en el directorio correspondiente.

Le ha pasado algo parecido y como lo solucionaron, ya la aplicación está en un servidor

Recibo este detalle en el header de la petición
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Hola Jose, estas seguro de que el archivo se llama `ajax.php` todo en minúsculas?

Comment: Si todo está en minúscula, el hecho es que ejecuta lo que el archivo se supone debe hacer, pero muestra el valor 404. Gracias